# Intersection of convex subsets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C(X)$ the intersection of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ convex containing a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that, if $X$ is compact then $C(X)$ is compact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $C(X)$ is compact, we can use Caratheodory's theorem, which states that any point in $C(X)$ can be written as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ix_i$$

where $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n+1}=1$, and $a_i\ge 0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n+1$.  In other words, the continuous function $X^{n+1}\times\Delta\to C(X)$, ($\Delta$ is the standard $n$-simplex), defined by:

$$\left(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i\cdot e_i\right)\longmapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_ix_i$$

is surjective.  Since $X$ and $\Delta$ are both compact, so is $X^{n+1}\times\Delta$.  Now use the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $X$ is compact, then it is closed and bounded by [Heine-Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), and so $X$ is contained inside some finite $n$-dimensional box.  This box is a convex set.

Comment: Why is $C(X)$ closed?

Comment: @lhf: Fair point, the hint only gets to the point of reducing compactness to closedness.